# How to disable and enable GUI of debian 10

Tags: debian, gui

Hello I want to disable my GUI and enable it again (debian 10 buster) for testing purposes is it possible?

Comment: what GUI are you talking about?

Comment: the graphical desktop interface on my debian 10 operation system

Comment: you are talking about the desktop manager then .... which one are you using?   .... also, be aware that you asked a simple yes/no question that has a `yes` answer .... is that really all you want to know?

Comment: @JohnLloydGementiza , In UNIX(contains GNU\linux OS), you have more than 10 GUI, So you need to tell your desktop manager. If you have `GDM`,  you can use `systemctl disable gdm3`, for `sddm`,  use `systemctl disable sddm`.

Answer (score 21):

To disable the GUI:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo reboot
```

To re-enable the GUI:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
sudo reboot
```

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 layers for each GUI in UNIX:

1. X : 
   It's low level application for using GUI, it supports keyboard, video card and so on. many years ago, `XFree86` was used in linux, Then replaced with `X.org` application, now you have `wayland`.
2. Window Manager : 
   each "Desktop Environment" uses itself Window Manager. Window Manager allow you to switch between windows, create title, close, minimize and some possibilities  for your Desktop Environnment, Gnome Desktop Environment uses `metacity` Window Manager, for list of Window Managers, you can visit [Window Managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers).
3. Desktop Manager : 
    Desktop Manager is login manager such as `GDM`, `KDM`, `SDDM`, `CDM` and so on.

Abobe 3 layers are your Desktop Environment, Desktop Environment such as `GNOME`, `KDE Plasma`, `awesome`,`LXDE` and so on.

When your Desktop Manager is started, above application will be started.

**But your question**:

for disable or enable as permanent your Desktop Manager :

`systemctl enable,disable YOUR_DESKTOP_MANAGER`
such as : `systemctl disable gdm3`

for stopping them:

`service  YOUR_DESKTOP_MANAGER start,stop`
such as : `service gdm3 stop`