# gdm doen't start on Debian 11

Tags: debian, gui, gdm

When I start Debian 11, it can't enter into GUI desktop. Everytime, I enter my name and my passwords then I enter the code:

```
su
systemctl start gdm
```

Then I can enter into the GUI desktop. How should I repair it so as I needn't enter thoese codes.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo systemctl get-default`?

Comment: **multi-user.target**  This is the result. I once modified this setting, so this shows this. @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable and enable GUI of debian 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569514/how-to-disable-and-enable-gui-of-debian-10)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I entered these codes: *sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target && sudo reboot*. Now I entered `sudo systemctl get-default` I will get `graphical.target `. Then I entered `sudo systemctl enable gdm` but I get `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy+, Also=, Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl. Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:`

Comment: Please take it to Debian's IRC channel. These are very basic questions and you probably shouldn't be using Debian in the first place. It's a very user-unfriendly distro which requires to read docs before you use it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks. Let me try. But I never use Debian's IRC channel before, so it may be difficult for me to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line:

```ini
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

to the `gdm.service`. For editing you can use:

```bash
sudo -e /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service
```

and finally try to enable `gdm` service:

**rebooting:**

```bash
sudo systemctl enable gdm
reboot
```

**without rebooting:**

```bash
sudo systemctl enable --now gdm
```

---

You can also use a symbolic link for your gdm service like this (without using the previous steps):

```bash
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants
reboot
```

Comment: This way can solve this problem. Good way.